# YouTube Data API v3 quotas

Tags: api, youtube

youtube data api v3 Queries per minute have 1,800,000 limit, but Queries per day have 10000 limit(see attachment), In our opinion, this is quite unreasonable, is it a bug? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obddj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/quota_and_compliance_audits

> Projects that enable the YouTube Data API have a default quota allocation of 10,000 units per day, an amount sufficient for the majority of our API users. You can see your quota usage on the Quotas page in the API Console.
>
> If you would like to request additional quota beyond the default allocation, you must first complete an audit to show that your project is in compliance with the YouTube API Services Terms of Service. This gives YouTube visibility into the intended use cases of large projects and ensures that YouTube's API services are being used in a manner that is free from abuse. Visit this link for additional details on complying with YouTube’s Developer Policies.